# Is there an ideal way to move from Staging to Production for Coldfusion code?

Tags: coldfusion

I am trying to work out a good way to run a staging server and a production server for hosting multiple Coldfusion sites.  Each site is essentially a fork of a repo, with site specific changes made to each.  I am looking for a good way to have this staging server move code (upon QA approval) to the production server.

One fanciful idea involved compiling the sites each into EAR files to be run on the production server, but I cannot seem to wrap my head around Coldfusion archives, plus I cannot see any good way of automating this, especially the deployment part.

What I have done successfully before is use subversion as a go between for a site, where once a site is QA'd the code is committed and then the production server's working directory would have an SVN update run, which would then trigger a code copy from the working directory to the actual live code.  This worked fine, but has many moving parts, and still required some form of server access to each server to run the commits and updates.  Plus this worked for an individual site, I think it may be a nightmare to setup and maintain this architecture for multiple sites.

Ideally I would want a group of developers to have FTP access with the ability to log into some control panel to mark a site for QA, and then have a QA person check the site and mark it as stable/production worthy, and then have someone see that a site is pending and click a button to deploy the updated site. (Any of those roles could be filled by the same person mind you)

Sorry if that last part wasn't so much the question, just a framework to understand my current thought process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Agree with @Nathan Strutz that Ant is a good tool for this purpose. Some more thoughts.

You want a repeatable build process that minimizes opportunities for deltas. With that in mind:

1. SVN export a build.
2. Tag the build in SVN.
3. Turn that export into a .zip, something with an installer, etc... idea being one unit to validate with a set of repeatable deployment steps.
4. Send the build to QA.
5. If QA approves deploy that build into production

Move whole code bases over as a build, rather than just changed files. This way you know what's put into place in production is the same thing that was validated. Refactor code so that configuration data is not overwritten by a new build.

As for actual production deployment, I have not come across a tool to solve the multiple servers, different code bases challenge. So I think you're best served rolling your own.

As an aside, in your situation I would think through an approach that allows for a standardized codebase, with a mechanism (i.e. an API) that allows for the customization you're describing. Otherwise managing each site as a "custom" project is very painful.

**Update**

**Learning Ant**: [Ant in Action](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/193239480X) [book].

**On Source Control**: for the situation you describe, I would maintain a core code base and  overlays per site. Export core, then site specific over it. This ensures any core updates that site specific changes don't override make it in.

Call this combination a "build". Do builds with Ant. Maintain an Ant script - or perhaps more flexibly an ant configuration file - per core & site combination. Track version number of core and site as part of a given build.

If your software is stuffed inside an installer ([Nullsoft Install Shield](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Main_Page) for instance) that should be part of the build. Otherwise you should generate a .zip file (.ear is a possibility as well, but haven't seen anyone actually do this with CF). Point being one file that encompasses the whole build.

This build file is what QA should validate. So validation includes deployment, configuration and functionality testing. See my answer for deployment on how this can flow.

**Deployment**:

If you want to automate deployment QA should be involved as well to validate it. Meaning QA would deploy / install builds using the same process on their servers before doing a staing to production deployment.

To do this I would create something that tracks what server receives what build file and whatever credentials and connection information is necessary to make that happen. Most likely via FTP. Once transferred, the tool would then extract the build file / run the installer. This last piece is an area I would have to research as to how it's possible to let one server run commands such as extraction or installation remotely.

Comment: Well, the system is set up to have a standardized codebase, but unfortunately it also needs to be separated out per site as well because we are not the only hosts for our product, and it needs to work on shared hosting solutions as well.  Currently we use Git for our source control, and each site is a branch of our repository, this turns into a problem, because we then need a separate tag for each site's QA ready/stable commit.  * What would you think the best way to automate the transport of the files from staging to production would be?

Answer (score 2):

You should look into Ant as a migration tool. It allows you to package your build process with a simple XML file that you can run from the command line or from within Eclipse. Creating an automated build process is great because it documents the process as well as executes it the same way, every time.

Ant can handle zipping and unzipping, copying around, making backups if needed, working with your subversion repository, transferring via FTP, compressing javascript and even calling a web address if you need to do something like flush the application memory or server cache once it's installed. You may be surprised with the things you can do with Ant.

To get started, I would recommend [the Ant manual](http://ant.apache.org/manual/) as your main resource, but look into existing Ant builds as a good starting point to get you going. I have [one on RIAForge](http://sqlsurfer.riaforge.org/index.cfm?event=page.svnview&path=&file=build.xml) for example that does some interesting stuff and calls a groovy script to do some more processing on my files during the build. If you [search riaforge for build.xml](http://www.google.com/search?q=site%3ariaforge.org+build.xml) files, you will come up with a great variety of them, many of which are directly for ColdFusion projects.

Comment: I have been looking into ant, do you have any recommended links for learning?